# How do i break these legs apart?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

So i trying to separate these two legs made from blocks. I want them to be able to move separately but NOT make them independent pieces. I tried using the rip tool but it told me that was an error. Here is a video of me trying to break them. https://webmshare.com/LPOVe

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the vertices along the middle part using shift, left click and then rip them using v, make sure to select both the back and front vertices

Comment: i already did that and it told me there was an error like i said in my original post

Comment: Make sure the all the faces were filled

Comment: i did. did you watch the webm?

Answer (score 0):

reddit helped me https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/7z5nrw/how_do_i_break_these_legs_apart/

Delete the faces in the middle then rip them. Hide vertices for one side at a time. then creates inside faces for each leg.